# If I try to steal from someone and then I get noticed. Will I always be enemy of that person?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I think I once stole from a girl. I get out of the area and come back and she's nice again.

Does an NPCs hostile status reset every time I go somewhere else?

Comment: Some better grammer would flow much more smoothly.  It's possible to understand what you're asking, but a bit more effort would make it sound much much better.

Comment: Can I ask, who is your follower? From your previous question about this behaviour, your follower is the constant. So depending on who it is (because certain followers react in certain ways when you steal things) it might be part of your problem.

Comment: The title and the question in the body are opposed, which makes it hard to give a clear yes or no. If it resets, then that's a yes to the body, which is a no to the title, because you aren't always their enemy.

Comment: I accidentally clicked on some clutter in a shop, immediately dropped it, and the shopkeeper has been mad at me ever since.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, yes. I have never come across a situation whether this was not true. If I am detected, then I will always be an enemy of the person or at least scolded. As Jim has already pointed out there are times when this association is not persistent and therefore you can leave the area and come back again, but I think that might not always be true and may not work all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, the NPC's are as dumb as a rock. But sometimes, I think, they'll send hired thugs after you. If you help them you can still become their friends.

Answer (score -1):

With stealing, if they see you, guards appear, and if your bounty goes down the next time they see you you they will not attack you, but they might say hostile lines of dialogue. They will also become not hostile if you pay your bounty while they are in the vicinity. If your bounty is low, and you run away then come back, they also might say hostile lines of dialogue, but won't attack. If they don't see you, the worst that might happen is hired thugs coming after you.

Basically, they might dislike you, but unless you have a high bounty they won't continue to attack you.